# Is there a best use API client pattern for Android?

Tags: java, android, rest, design-patterns, serialization

This question may seem subjective because I'm not sure how to ask it so that it leads to an objective answer. Is there a best use design pattern for creating an REST API client in Android?

Typically I:

- put all my API methods in a static APIClient class
- write manual serialization code into each model I'm getting from the API (mostly because sometimes adding a serialization library seems like more complication).
- let the Activities handle the success and error responses.

However I've also seen a lot of code that has distinct classes for each type of API call, extending classes like AbstractAction and AbstractResponse. It seems like a lot of people have their own, very different, ways of doing it, which is strange because writing an API client is one of the first things you have to do when writing an app. So is there a right way to do it, or at least a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best* pattern is a combination of various patterns. it's subjected to the type of activity you are supposed to do.

For some recommended design patterns see: [Google I/O 2010 - Android REST client applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)

For accessing the rest API, there's already several libraries which are  designed for this specific purpose (e.g., retrofit, volley, being some of them) they abstract the network access as well as the serialization, doing these by yourself, seems overkill unless there's specific reason to do so.

For example, in [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) it's easy as this:

*the API as an interface*

```
public interface GitHubService { 
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user); 
}
```

*using with an adapter*

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder() 
      .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
      .build(); 

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);

List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

This does all the serialization, and deserialization required (with retrofit 2.0 the serialization is detached and should be plugged-in via modules).

There is official example/tutorial on volley [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)